# <hr> tag: change background color

Tags: html, css

I have a page that needs an `<hr>`.  The page's background is black, and the `<hr>` always has a white background above and below the actual line.  I tried giving it a background-color of black, but that did not work.  Any suggestions on how to remove this unwanted light-colored background?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add your code to this question?  It's not entirely clear what you're seeing or what you want it to look like.  If it's not possible to add your code, then use your browser's developer tools to inspect the white part to see where the styling is coming from.

Comment: Several CSS reset libraries does something like this to make `hr` render equal cross browsers: `hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}`